# Implement an elastic rope in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, game-physics, skphysicsjoint

I am working on a simple game that has an elastic rope fixed to the middle of the screen which also has a ball linked to the other end of the rope. By moving your finger across the screen you can move the ball and the idea is being able to fling the ball upwards by pulling it towards the bottom.

My code so far looks like this:

```
var ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Ball")

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    var ropeSegments = [SKSpriteNode]()

    let ropeHolder = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "RopeHolder")
    ropeHolder.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
    ropeSegments.append(ropeHolder)
    addChild(ropeHolder)

    ropeHolder.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ropeHolder.size.width / 2)
    ropeHolder.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false

    for i in 0..<30 {
        let ropeSegment = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "RopeTexture")
        let offset = ropeSegment.size.height * CGFloat(i + 1)
        ropeSegment.position = CGPoint(x: ropeHolder.position.x, y: ropeHolder.position.y - offset)
        ropeSegments.append(ropeSegment)
        addChild(ropeSegment)

        ropeSegment.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: ropeSegment.size)
    }

    for i in 1..<31 {
        let nodeA = ropeSegments[i - 1]
        let nodeB = ropeSegments[i]
        let joint = SKPhysicsJointPin.joint(withBodyA: nodeA.physicsBody!, bodyB: nodeB.physicsBody!, anchor: CGPoint(x: nodeA.frame.midX, y: nodeA.frame.midY))

        physicsWorld.add(joint)
    }

    ball.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: ropeSegments.last!.position.y - ball.size.height / 2)
    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball.size.width / 2)
    addChild(ball)

    let joint = SKPhysicsJointPin.joint(withBodyA: ropeSegments.last!.physicsBody!, bodyB: ball.physicsBody!, anchor: CGPoint(x: ropeSegments.last!.frame.midX, y: ropeSegments.last!.frame.midY))
    physicsWorld.add(joint)

    let moveAction = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: frame.midX - 100, y: frame.midY), duration: 0.5)
    ball.run(moveAction)
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let point = touch.location(in: self)
        ball.position = point
    }
}
```

the rope behaves pretty much like a real life rope but it's not elastic at all. I am able to pull the ball as much as I want but the rope nodes go back to default state in a really slow manner so it's not possible to fling the ball around.

I tried using `SKPhysicsJointSpring` instead of `SKPhysicsJointPin` but it behaves pretty much the same. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try different values for the spring joint's damping and/or frequency properties?

Comment: Yes I tried some values for them but it just behaves the same way as a `SKPhysicsJointPin`. Maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Definitely use a chain of Spring Joints. You might need to set the frequency to very high levels and damping to very low levels, and then tweak.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I may have a solution for this.

Comment: Well I didn't have the time to work on it yet. What is your idea?